# I am trying to add a cognito user through a post confirmation lambda but no luck

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to add a cognito user through a post confirmation lambda. I am not getting any errors and I am able to log success message but user is still not showing in the user group.

snippet of my code:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

try {
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(groupUserParams).promise();
} catch (err){
  console.log(`Add to ${groupUserParams.GroupName} error: ${err}`);
}
```

Comment: stupid mistake. did not have the await keyword..

Comment: You can answer your own question, and then accept it. Will be more helpful for others.

Comment: cool.. will do that then.. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the "await" keyword before calling the method solved it for me.